# Firebase Analyticsを導入しましたが、イベントが送信されないです。設定が間違ってますでしょうか？

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

Firebase AnalyticsをiOSアプリに導入しました。
以下のヘルプを見ながら設定しました。
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?hl=ja&platform=ios

そしてアプリを起動してイベントが計測される認識でいましたがされませんでした。
管理画面のリアルタイムダッシュボードでも計測されていませんでした。
上記URLの設定を行うことで、以下のイベントがデフォルトで計測される認識でした。
・first_open
・session_start
・screen_view

そして、検証で以下のイベントコードを記載して送ってみました。
Analytics.logEvent("test_event",["test_param":"test_value"])
そうすると、test_eventというイベントがリアルタイムダッシュボードで計測され、
そして上記のようなデフォルトイベントも計測されました。

このことから、
何かしらこちらでイベント計測をしないと、デフォルトのイベントは計測されないのでしょうか？
SDKを入れただけで、デフォルトは計測されるものだと思っておりました。（そうなると、screen_viewを計測するためには、各ViewControllerに、logEventコードを記載しないといけないのでしょうか？）

よろしくお願いします。